# how to post string as byte[] using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I need to post my query string as byte[] with retrofit 2; how can I do this? is any converter for this purpose ?
when I use this code :

```
Call<ResponseBody> login(@Body byte[] body);
```

I get this error :

```
Unable to create @Body converter for byte[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic `RequestBody`, for example interface would look like:

```
@POST("/login")
Call<ResponseBody> login(@Body RequestBody body);
```

and then:

```
final byte[] byteArray = ...;
RequestBody typedBytes = new RequestBody() {
    @Override
    public MediaType contentType() {
        return MediaType.parse("application/json");
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
        sink.write(byteArray);
    }
};
rest.login(typedBytes).enqueue(...);
```

MIME type depends on your case of course.

Comment: I want to convert this string to byte[] : `username=myname&password=mypass`. what MIME type should I use?

Comment: Hmm this looks suspicious, why you want to send your query as byte array instead of using Retrofit's `@Query`? Still, `text/plain` should be fine.

Comment: No. It didn't work. I think I'm have to use volley instead of retrofit :|

Comment: Still, question is why are you sending apparently query parameters as byte array?

Comment: because the target API wants this!